# Removing Object of ArrayList by using it's unique ID

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having problems with the functions of the `ArrayList`. I'm trying to remove objects of an ArrayList by specifying their `ID`. I have a `createEmployee` method in my `Main` class:

```
public void createEmployee(){
    String typeofemployee = sc.nextLine();

    UUID uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID();
    String x = "" + uniqueID;
    System.out.println("The new ID of the " + typeofemployee + " is: " + uniqueID + ".");

    System.out.println("What's the name of the new " + typeofemployee + "?");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What's the salary of the new " + typeofemployee + "?");
    salary = sc.nextDouble();
    Employee employee = new Employee(x, name, salary);

    switch (typeofemployee) {

        case "Employee":
            reusaxcorp.registerEmployee(employee);
            break;

        // other cases
    }
}
```

And I have an `ArrayList`, to which I add employees by registering them with the following method (down below there's the `removeEmployee` method).

```
public class ReusaxCorp extends Main {

Scanner input;
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
final String END_OF_LINE = System.lineSeparator();

public void registerEmployee(Employee employee){
    employees.add(employee);
}

public void retrieveEmployee() {
    for(Employee employee: employees){
        System.out.println("ID: " + employee.ID + END_OF_LINE + "Name: " + employee.name + END_OF_LINE + "Salary: " + employee.grossSalary);
        System.out.println(); // an empty line for each employee
    }
}

public void removeEmployee(){
    employees.remove(0); 
    /* I also tried this, but it doesn't work either
    Iterator<Employee> iter = employees.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Which eployee do you want to remove? Type in his/her ID. ");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            Employee employee = iter.next();
            if (employees.equals(number)) {
                employees.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    */
}
```

The only way I know of is just to write `employees.remove(index)` and removing an employee by specifying his index. **So I want to know if it's possible to remove an employee by specifying his unique ID.** Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `removeIf` introduced in Java 8 for the shortest code.

```
employees.removeIf(e -> e.getId().equals(id));
```

You might also want to consider using a `Map`, since the ids are unique and then you can access (and/or remove) an employee very easily and efficiently with just the id. You can also use `Map.values()` to get all the employees as a collection (though not a `List`).

```
Map<String, Employee> employees = new HashMap<>();
employees.put(e.getId().toString(), e); // Or use UUID directly as key
employees.remove(idToBeRemoved);
```

Comment: I thought this was the same as `remove(Object)` (but with a predicate to improve the implementation and the condition) but this one will remove every instance matching, instead of the first occurence.

Comment: Yup, perhaps it should've been named `filter()` to keep in line with streams. Although since `filter()` doesn't modify the original collection, it makes sense not to.

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 8 there is a `removeIf()` method. You can use it as follows:

```
employees.removeIf(employee -> employee.getId().equals(removeId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use smth. like that:

```
public void removeEmployee(int removeId) {
 Employee empToRemove = employees.get(removeId);
 Iterator<Employee> iter = employees.iterator();
 while(iterator.hasNext()){
  Employee emp = iterator.next();
  if(emp.equals(empToRemove)){
   iterator.remove();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. One way would be to use an `Iterator`. You are using the wrong syntax for it. But your approach is correct. Change it to

```
public void removeEmployee(String id){
    Iterator<Employee> it = employees.iterator();
    while(it.hashNext()){
        Employee employee = it.next();
        if(employee.getId().equals(id)){
            it.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The call to get the user input would be passed to the method `removeEmployee`.

Answer (score 1):

Previous Java 8, we had to use the `remove` method.
Since the ID is unique, this is a possible `equals` implementation.

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    //check for instance and null

    Employee e = (Employee) o;
    return this.uid.equals(e.uid);
}
```

Then, simply call [`ArrayList.remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)

```
list.remove(employeeToRemove);
```

This doesn't need to be the same instance, just to have the same UID, so you could simply do

```
Employee employeeToRemove = new Employee(UUID)
list.remove(employeeToRemove);
```

It might be a bit more useless to create an instance to remove another one, but it is also useless to loop since there is method to do it ;)

Note, with `equals` being implemented, you should implements `hashcode` to be safe.

```
public int hashcode(){
    return UID.hashcode();
}
```

! All my codes are simplistic and don't check for `null` to be shorter !